# How to store a custom date and be modify by adding days?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need advice on the following topic: I have a project that creates custom emails with info from some materials, where `@DUEDATE` is a column from a table and is the result of

```
SET @LV_DUEDATE =  DATEADD(day, @PV,GETDATE())
```

where `@PV` are the days to add to the current datetime, then we subtract 15 days from the result of `DUEDATE` and insert that result to the column `@EXPDV` using

```
SET @LV_EXPDV = DATEADD(day, -15, @LV_DUEDATE)
```

The value of @PV is stored by a screen from another program.

It runs ok, but now I need to add a custom date, for example in other column add 2019-12-31 (yyyy-mm-dd) and then add with the days using a value from @PV, 2019-12-31 custom date (can be any date) + 20 days from @PV = DUEDATE result 2020-01-19 and insert that result to a column with date format, everything must be date formats, any ideas of how to insert the custom date?

Thank you!

```
@PRF VARCHAR(20),
@PSPN VARCHAR(20),
@PSDRCV VARCHAR(20),
@PSLOT VARCHAR (20),
@PSQRCV VARCHAR (20),
@NAX VARCHAR (20),
@EXPD VARCHAR (20),
@PV INT

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
         @LV_PSPN VARCHAR(20),
         @LV_PRF VARCHAR (20),
         @LV_PSDRCV VARCHAR(20),
         @LV_PSLOT VARCHAR(20),
         @LV_PSQRCV VARCHAR (20),
         @LV_DUEDATE DATETIME,
         @LV_NAX VARCHAR(20),
         @LV_EXPD VARCHAR (20),
         @LV_EXPDV DATETIME,
         @LV_PV INT

    SET @LV_PRF = @PRF
    SET @LV_PSPN = RTRIM(@PSPN)
    SET @LV_PSDRCV = @PSDRCV
    SET @LV_PSLOT = @PSLOT
    SET @LV_PSQRCV = @PSQRCV
    SET @PV = @PV

    SET @LV_DUEDATE =  DATEADD(day, @PV, GETDATE())  --Current date where I add the days as @pv and got the column DUEDATE on my table--

    SET @LV_EXPDV = DATEADD(day, -15, @LV_DUEDATE)  --The result of DUEDATE Minus 15 days--

    SET @LV_NAX = @NAX
    SET @LV_EXPD = @EXPD

    INSERT INTO QT_ShelfLifev3 (PSPN, PRF, PSDRCV, PSLOT, PSQRCV, Dateadded, DUEDATE, EXPD, EXPDV, PV) 
    VALUES (@PSPN, @PRF, @PSDRCV, @PSLOT, @PSQRCV, GETDATE(), @LV_DUEDATE, @EXPD, @LV_EXPDV, @PV)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. [Date have no display format.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: Store a custom date on a column and modifier that date by adding days and that result will be display on another column